# How to pass extra dynamic rows created from jquery to contrller in array codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

This is my code, where a user can add dynamic rows by clicking add more link.

But when I print

```
print_r($this->input->post('name1'));
```

in controller, it prints only first value but I want all values of array.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <table rules="all" style="background:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:14px;" >Name</td>
            <td style="font-size:14px;">Email</td>
            <td style="font-size:14px;">Mobile</td>
            <td><span style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);">Add More</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowId">
            <td><input name="name1[]" type="text"  value="" size="17%"/></td>
            <td><input name="age1[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
            <td><input name="relation1[]" type="text"  value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="addedRows"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rowCount = 1;
        function addMoreRows(frm) {
            rowCount ++;
            var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input name="name1[]" type="text" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td><td><input name="age1[]" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td><td><input name="relation1[]" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td></tr> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');">Delete</a></p>';
            jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
        }

        function removeRow(removeNum) {
            jQuery('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it to another variable and printing it like this:

```
$name1 = $this->input->post('name1');
print_r($name1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view page:

put `<?php echo form_open_multipart('test/add_member'); ?>` instead of

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
```

In Controller: Dynamic input array data can handle as follows, this may help you..thanks!

```
public function add_member()
{
 if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
  redirect('auth/login');
 }
 $itemCount = count($this->input->post('name'));
 $itemValues=0;
 $query = "INSERT INTO You_table_name(name, age,    relation) VALUES ";
 $queryValue = "";
 for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
  $name = $this->input->post('name');
  $age = $this->input->post('age');
  $relation = $this->input->post('relation');
  if(!empty($name[$i])) {
   $itemValues++;
   if($queryValue!="") {
    $queryValue .= ",";
   }
   $queryValue .= "('" . $name[$i] . "', '" . $age[$i] . "', '" . $relation[$i] . "')";
  }
 }
 $sql = $query.$queryValue; 
 if($itemValues!=0) {
  if (!$this->db->query($sql)) {
//      echo "FALSE";
  }else {
//       echo "TRUE";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: HI thank you for answer but i am not getting array value to controller itself

Comment: did u get $itemCount in ur controller?

Comment: If ur $itemCount is having correct value u can see the whole input data by echoing the $sql variable as insert query..just try this...if u need more support pls let me know...thanks!

Comment: I am getting only one ...the rows added by jquery and if i enter values in that rows are not getting

Comment: print_r($this->input->post('name1')); in controller i am printing this

Comment: public function add_member($param1 = '', $param2 = '')
 {
   if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()  ) {
     redirect('auth/login');
   }
   
   $dbs = $this->input->post('name1'     );
   print_r($dbs);die;

Comment: I Just edit my answer.. can u pls echo $sql variable in the controller?

Comment: I am not inserting to database only...before inserting to database i am printing the array but i am getting only first value from view

Comment: Before the data insertion Pls check the output of echo $sql = $query.$queryValue;  exit; and pls show me the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the POST item, so you print out all the `POST` values. Also, I suggest incremented the 'name' atttribute as well, so you will have name1, name2, name 3 etc, or just remove the number because you are using an array.

If you want to increment the 'name' attribute
To loop:

```
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($this->input->post('name1') as $key => $value)
    {
        $counter++;
        // $value = name1
        echo $this->input->post('age". $counter ."');
        echo $this->input->post('relation". $counter ."');
    }
```

With array
To loop:

```
    foreach ($this->input->post('name1') as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value;
        $this->input->post('age1');
        $this->input->post('relation1');
    }
```

I havent tested it myself

Comment: To do this i am not getting array values to controller itself

Comment: what do you see, nothing at all? @RaghuDarshan

Comment: I am getting only first values. and rows added by jquery and values are not coming

Comment: hmm, strange that its not working. I have the same principle I am using for my dynamically added rows and it working just fine. Try removing the `$key =>` in the for each, idk if codeigniter has a problem with that

Comment: here is what I use:
`foreach ($this->request->post['item'] as $value)
     {
      echo $value . "<br />";
}`

@RaghuDarshan

Comment: $this->input->post('name1') if  i print this in controller it print only first value but it should print all values right?